# Const char* не совместим с LPCWSTR

Tags: c++, c

При обьявлении `Rus` вызывает ошибку, что Const char* не совместим с LPCWSTR

```
char* Rus(const char* text)  
{
    CharToOem(text,bufRus);     return bufRus;           
}
```

Comment: LPC**W**TR: w - wide. Не сhar, а wchar.

Comment: И это правда - `сonst char*` не совместим с `LPCWSTR`.

Comment: @AnT Подскажите, правильно понял, мне просто нужно добавить L, чтобы получилось `CharToOem(L(text),bufRus);`

Comment: @AnT, не могли бы помочь в решении моего вопроса по поводу редактирования структуры? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/914704/const-char-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%81-lpcwstr